# Python library for API call which is faster than requests

Tags: python-2.7, api, python-requests

I am trying to get some data using API calls in my Python script. I am currently using the requests library which takes about 47 mins for 5K rows. Is there any other library in python faster than requests?

Answer (score 0):

For synchronous calls, `pycurl` is the fastest.